# Adding a @layer to injected CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a React app that uses Material-UI as a framework. I want to implement the @layer to my custom CSS files but for that, I need all the injected CSS from Material-UI to be also inside a 'third-party' @layer. I'm asking how can I control the injected CSS so that I can put its content in a Layer?